# How to tell if an adjective listed in a vocabulary is third-declension or first-second-declension?

Tags: adjective

In Keller's Learn to Read Latin:

> When a third-declension adjective has three forms in the nominative singular, the vocabulary entry contains the same elements as the entry for a first-second-declension adjective: the masculine, feminine, and neuter singular nominative.

So how can I tell if an adjective listed in a vocabulary is third-declension or first-second-declension? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The endings will tell:
In singular nominative the feminine ending is *-a* and the neuter ending is *-um* in declensions 1 and 2.
The same endings in declension 3 are never *-a* and *-um*.

The masculine form alone is not enough to tell the difference, as looking at *pulcher* and *acer* will show you.
Only when you see *pulchra & pulchrum* and *acris & acre* can you tell which declension to follow.

There are many possible ways you might formulate a detection rule.
What I suggest works, but I'm not saying this is the only one that does.
The declension tables will be your guide here.
The singular nominative can be a bit irregular in the third declension and sometimes for the second declension masculine, but feminines and neuters of declension 1/2 are regular.